How do I control the angle of CardView projection, the shadow currently used in the cardElevation outlineSpotShadowColor control?
Component used: androidx.cardview:cardview Version used: 1.0.0 Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Huawei Tablet in Android 12
I want to achieve the projection effect of a point light source (the position of the light source is the top-center position of the widget itself), but I found that the projection effect will be different when CardView is in different positions of the screen.
I consulted the relevant documents and explained that the position of the point light source is in the top-center position of the screen. I want to ask whether it is possible to achieve the point light projection effect based on the widget itself（top-center)?
here is my test code:
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardCornerRadius"
    app:cardElevation="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


and the outlineSpotShadowColor property is dynamically set in the code based on the domain color of the image.
And I got this:

Thank you for your answer in advance！
No matter where the CardView is located on the screen, its shadow is normally based on its own vertical orientation.

Nope, not really, not without some major hackery, anyway. The light source values for material shadows are set on a renderer object that belongs to the Window, so any modifications will affect all of the shadows in a given Activity or Dialog. If the native shadows aren't necessarily a requirement, you might be better off drawing your own shadows manually, or maybe finding a library that does it.
